# ASP.NET C# RDLC IFF condition gives error

Tags: c#, asp.net, report, rdlc

I need to print notes into the rdlc report. Due to the long notes i wrote a substring function to reduce the size of the notes. It works perfectly for the notes which has length more than 30. But it shows error for the notes which has length lesser than 30. So i decided to give a IFF condition for rdlc report field. But again it shows error ( for notes less than 30 in length). Please suggest me is there any wrong in this IFF condition, else please suggest me some alternate solution for this problem.
Here my code.

```
=IIF(Fields!Notes.Value.ToString().Length() >30,(Fields!Notes.Value.ToString().Substring(0,30)),Fields!Notes.Value)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you try this:

```
=iif(Len(Fields!Notes.Value)>30,Left(Fields!Notes.Value,30), Fields!Notes.Value)
```

and if you are not sure that datatype of Fields!Notes.Value will be string then simply replace `'Fields!Notes.Value'` with `CStr(Fields!Notes.Value)` everywhere